# Formula to remove special characters and replace space with dash

Tags: formula

I have a URLName text field that needs to copy another text field with the following format

**Title text field** : A New Article

**URLName text field** : A-New-Article

Basically spaces are replaced by dashes.

So far I have created a formula that does exactly that

SUBSTITUTE( {!Title} , " ", "-")

replacing all the spaces with a dash

The problem I have is that sometimes users wants to write a more descriptive title with special characters. But when doing so, I have an error.
Let's say I write the following in the Title field

Text field Title : A New Article was created / Account #5: Id.231

I get an error as the URL field does not accept special characters (e.g. , / : ; ! " * ...etc)

**FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Invalid URL name. The URL name can include only unicode characters and hyphens, and it can't begin or end with a hyphen.: URL Name.**

Is there a way to create a formula to ignore all special characters and at the same time replace spaces with dashed to be left only with a format with dashed

So for example

**Text field Title** : A New Article was created / Account #5: Id.231

**URLName field**:     A-New-Article-was-created-Account-5-Id231

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Formula is not as robust as the likes of Apex to convert/substitute the special characters. For your above example, a static formula can be built using a nested `SUBSTITUTE` approach such as

```
SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(Title , " / ", " ")," ", "-"), " #" , ""), ": " , " "), "." , "")
```

Moving to Apex, you can use [Patterns and Matchers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm).